# Common inequality

Tags: inequality, jensen-inequality

I was trying to prove that for arbitrary $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $p\in\mathbb{N}$ it holds

$(A+B)^p \leq 2^{p-1}(A^p+B^p)$

I'd appreciate some advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722260/how-to-show-stp-le-2p-1sp-tp-for-p-gt1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555002/proof-2n-1anbnabn.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong! Try $p=3$, $A=-2$ and $B=1$.

For $A\geq0$ and $B\geq0$ your inequality it's just Jensen for $f(x)=x^p$:
$$\frac{A^p+B^p}{2}\geq\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)^p$$

Comment: Oh, you're right. I was confused. Thank you very much for clearing that up.

Comment: @Twexco If so, vote please.